# How to set environment variables in fastlane?

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, fastlane

I had read the documents but I am still confused where to set the environment variables in the fastfile or the bash_profile. Can you please help me out with that?

What I want to achieve is to set the apple developer credentials in fastfile and should not ask again if any user takes pull of my code and try to build it.

I am writing this in fastlane file. Let me know if I am wrong.

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

ENV["FASTLANE_DONT_STORE_PASSWORD"] = "1"
ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = ""
ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = ""

desc "GENERATE SCREENSHOT"
lane :Snaps do
capture_screenshots
end

end
```

Answer (score 42):

You can add environment variables in `before_all`. Try this.

```
platform :ios do
  before_all do
    ENV["FASTLANE_DONT_STORE_PASSWORD"] = "1"
    ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = ""
    ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = ""
  end

  desc "GENERATE SCREENSHOT"
  lane :Snaps do
    capture_screenshots
  end
end
```

---

To not store your keys in git, you can pass all parameters of all actions using environment variables.

You can edit your `~/.bash_profile` to include something like

```
export FASTLANE_DONT_STORE_PASSWORD ="1"
export FASTLANE_USER =""
export FASTLANE_PASSWORD =""
```

Comment: So either of the above way is correct right? Any flag to set for match password?

Comment: You can also [create a file named `.env` inside your `fastlane` folder](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#environment-variables).

Comment: First one is correct as far as you are not adding your fastfile to git (you don’t want to push you logins and password to repo). Second is good because your credentials stays on your local machine. I am not aware of anything like match password.

Comment: @Bilal For match password you can use MATCH_PASSWORD env variable.

Comment: I did as you mentioned. I added above to git and used other system to generate the build. But it still asks for Apple dev credentials. I doubt it's not setting above env vars.

Comment: I think the second way will run the environment variable with every bash script I execute in terminal. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to use "sh" instead of  setting from string ? , for example to get the output from a sh command